# why nhibernate does exit execution during select

Tags: nhibernate

when i make a selection of collection of PREVISION nhibernate exit execution with messages:
i don't know whether there's an infinte loop or anything else.
my computer fan start turning so quickly and warm up.

as a notice when PREVISION table is empty every goes right no problem.
i'm using ORacle 10g

please i need your solution.

```
 The thread '<No Name>' (0x570) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 The thread '<No Name>' (0x1200) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 The thread '<No Name>' (0xb68) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 The thread '<No Name>' (0x10b0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 The thread '<No Name>' (0xc84) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 The thread '<No Name>' (0x1004) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 The thread '<No Name>' (0x604) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 The thread '<No Name>' (0xbb4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).


    //code:



using Iesi.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System;


namespace Sample.FluentNHibernate.Domain.Objects
{
 public class PREVISION
 {
    public PREVISION() { }

    public virtual long ID_PREVISION { get; set; }

    public virtual REVISION_PROGRAMME REVISION_PROGRAMME { get; set; }
    public virtual ORGANISATION ORGANISATION { get; set; }
    public virtual BARRAGE BARRAGE { get; set; }
    public virtual PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL { get; set; }

    public virtual long BAR_ID_ORGANISATION { get; set; }
    public virtual long MOIS_PREVISION { get; set; }
    public virtual int ID_BAR { get; set; }
    public virtual float HAUT { get; set; }
    public virtual float VOL { get; set; }
    public virtual float CONTRAINTE { get; set; }
    public virtual float RESERVE { get; set; }
    public virtual float FREQUENCE { get; set; }
    public virtual long ANNEE_TYPE { get; set; }
    public virtual float VALEUR_MIN { get; set; }
    public virtual float EVAPORATION { get; set; }
    public virtual float FUITES { get; set; }
    public virtual float AEP { get; set; }
    public virtual float IRRIGATION { get; set; }
    public virtual float AUTRES { get; set; }
    public virtual float DVTE { get; set; }
    public virtual float DATATION_AEP { get; set; }
    public virtual float DATATION_IRRIG { get; set; }
    public virtual float VALEUR_FREQUENCE { get; set; }
    public virtual float VALEUR_ANNEE_TYPE { get; set; }
    public virtual long ANNEE_MIN { get; set; }
    public virtual long TE { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        var t = obj as PREVISION;
        if (t == null)
            return false;
        if (this.ID_PREVISION == t.ID_PREVISION
            && this.REVISION_PROGRAMME.ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME == 
   t.REVISION_PROGRAMME.ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (this.ID_PREVISION  + "|" + this.REVISION_PROGRAMME.ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME     
  ).GetHashCode();
    }
  }
}



//

using Iesi.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System;


  namespace Sample.FluentNHibernate.Domain.Objects
 {
  public class REVISION_PROGRAMME
  {
    public REVISION_PROGRAMME()
    {
        PREVISIONS = new HashedSet<PREVISION>();
    }
    public virtual long ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME { get; set; }

    public virtual ORGANISATION ORGANISATION { get; set; }
    public virtual PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<PREVISION> PREVISIONS { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime DATE_REVISION { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        var t = obj as REVISION_PROGRAMME;
        if (t == null)
            return false;
        if (this.ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME == t.ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME
            && this.PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL.ID_PROGRAMME == 
        t.PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL.ID_PROGRAMME)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (this.ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME + "|" + 
    this.PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL.ID_PROGRAMME).GetHashCode();
      }

    }
  }



//

using Iesi.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System;


namespace Sample.FluentNHibernate.Domain.Objects
{

 public class PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL
 {
    public PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL()
    {
        FREQUENCE_APPORTS = new HashedSet<FREQUENCE_APPORT>();
        REVISION_PROGRAMMES = new HashedSet<REVISION_PROGRAMME>();
    }

    public virtual int ID_PROGRAMME { get; set; }

    public virtual ORGANISATION ORGANISATION { get; set; }
    public virtual BARRAGE BARRAGE { get; set; }
    public virtual SYSTEME_HYDRAULIQUE SYSTEME_HYDRAULIQUE { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<FREQUENCE_APPORT> FREQUENCE_APPORTS { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<REVISION_PROGRAMME> REVISION_PROGRAMMES { get; set; }

    public virtual long? ID_BAR { get; set; }
    public virtual long? ID_SYSTEME_HYDRAULIQUE { get; set; }
    public virtual long BAR_ID_ORGANISATION { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DATE_PROGRAMME { get; set; }
    public virtual long SYS_ID_ORGANISATION { get; set; }
    public virtual long TYPE_DATA { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        var t = obj as PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL;
        if (t == null)
            return false;
        if (this.ID_PROGRAMME == t.ID_PROGRAMME && this.ORGANISATION.Id == 
    t.ORGANISATION.Id)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (this.ID_PROGRAMME + "|" + this.ORGANISATION.Id).GetHashCode();
    }
  }
 }



//

 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;
 using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
 using Sample.FluentNHibernate.Domain.Objects;

 namespace Sample.FluentNHibernate.Domain.Mappings
{
public class PREVISIONMap : ClassMap<PREVISION>
{
    public PREVISIONMap()
    {
        Table("PREVISION");
        LazyLoad();

        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.ID_PREVISION, "ID_PREVISION")
            //.KeyReference(x => x.PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL, "ID_PROGRAMME", 
         "ID_ORGANISATION");
            .KeyReference(x => x.REVISION_PROGRAMME, "ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME", 
         "ID_PROGRAMME", "ID_ORGANISATION");

        Id(x => 
        x.ID_PREVISION).GeneratedBy.Sequence("S_PREVISION").Column("ID_PREVISION");

        //References(x => x.REVISION_PROGRAMME).Columns("ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME", 
        "ID_PROGRAMME", "ID_ORGANISATION").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
        References(x => x.PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL).Columns("ID_PROGRAMME", 
       "ID_ORGANISATION").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
        References(x => x.BARRAGE).Columns("ID_BAR", 
        "ID_ORGANISATION").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
        References(x => 
        x.ORGANISATION).Column("ID_ORGANISATION").Not.Insert().Not.Update();

        Map(x => x.BAR_ID_ORGANISATION).Column("BAR_ID_ORGANISATION");
        Map(x => x.MOIS_PREVISION).Column("MOIS_PREVISION");
        Map(x => x.ID_BAR).Column("ID_BAR");
        Map(x => x.HAUT).Column("HAUT");
        Map(x => x.VOL).Column("VOL");
        Map(x => x.CONTRAINTE).Column("CONTRAINTE");
        Map(x => x.RESERVE).Column("RESERVE");
        Map(x => x.FREQUENCE).Column("FREQUENCE");
        Map(x => x.ANNEE_TYPE).Column("ANNEE_TYPE");
        Map(x => x.VALEUR_MIN).Column("VALEUR_MIN");
        Map(x => x.EVAPORATION).Column("EVAPORATION");
        Map(x => x.FUITES).Column("FUITES");
        Map(x => x.AEP).Column("AEP");
        Map(x => x.IRRIGATION).Column("IRRIGATION");
        Map(x => x.AUTRES).Column("AUTRES");
        Map(x => x.DVTE).Column("DVTE");
        Map(x => x.DATATION_AEP).Column("DATATION_AEP");
        Map(x => x.DATATION_IRRIG).Column("DATATION_IRRIG");
        Map(x => x.VALEUR_FREQUENCE).Column("VALEUR_FREQUENCE");
        Map(x => x.VALEUR_ANNEE_TYPE).Column("VALEUR_ANNEE_TYPE");
        Map(x => x.ANNEE_MIN).Column("ANNEE_MIN");
        Map(x => x.TE).Column("TE");
      }
    }
 }


 //

 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;
 using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
 using Sample.FluentNHibernate.Domain.Objects;

  namespace Sample.FluentNHibernate.Domain.Mappings
 {
 public class REVISION_PROGRAMMEMap : ClassMap<REVISION_PROGRAMME>
 {

    public REVISION_PROGRAMMEMap()
    {
        Table("REVISION_PROGRAMME");
        LazyLoad();

        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME, "ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME")
            .KeyReference(x => x.PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL, "ID_PROGRAMME", 
    "ID_ORGANISATION");

        Id(x => 
    x.ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME).GeneratedBy.Sequence("S_REVISION_PROGRAMME")
   .Column("ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME");

        References(x =>     
     x.ORGANISATION).Column("ID_ORGANISATION").Not.Insert().Not.Update();

        Map(x => x.DATE_REVISION).Column("DATE_REVISION");

        HasMany(x => x.PREVISIONS)
            .KeyColumns.Add("ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME", "ID_PROGRAMME", "ID_ORGANISATION")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.Delete();
       }
    }
  }


 //

 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;
 using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
 using Sample.FluentNHibernate.Domain.Objects;

 namespace Sample.FluentNHibernate.Domain.Mappings
{
  public class PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNELMap : ClassMap<PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL>
  {
    public PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNELMap()
    {
        Table("PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL");
        LazyLoad();

        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.ID_PROGRAMME, "ID_PROGRAMME")
            .KeyReference(x => x.ORGANISATION, "ID_ORGANISATION");

        Id(x => 
    x.ID_PROGRAMME).GeneratedBy.Sequence("S_PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL")
  .Column("ID_PROGRAMME");

        References(x => x.BARRAGE).Columns("ID_BAR",    
   "ID_ORGANISATION").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
        References(x => x.SYSTEME_HYDRAULIQUE).Columns("ID_SYSTEME_HYDRAULIQUE",   
  "ID_ORGANISATION").Not.Insert().Not.Update();

        Map(x => x.BAR_ID_ORGANISATION).Column("BAR_ID_ORGANISATION");
        Map(x => x.ID_BAR).Column("ID_BAR");
        Map(x => x.ID_SYSTEME_HYDRAULIQUE).Column("ID_SYSTEME_HYDRAULIQUE");
        Map(x => x.DATE_PROGRAMME).Column("DATE_PROGRAMME");
        Map(x => x.SYS_ID_ORGANISATION).Column("SYS_ID_ORGANISATION");
        Map(x => x.TYPE_DATA).Column("TYPE_DATA");

        HasMany(x => x.FREQUENCE_APPORTS)
            .KeyColumns.Add("ID_PROGRAMME", "ID_ORGANISATION")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.Delete();
        HasMany(x => x.REVISION_PROGRAMMES)
            .KeyColumns.Add("ID_PROGRAMME", "ID_ORGANISATION")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.Delete();
      }
     }
   }



 //code to retrive the collection PREVISION 



  IList<PREVISION> previsions =    
  repositoryPrev.RetrieveListByFourColumn("ORGANISATION.Id", id_org, 
  "PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL.ID_PROGRAMME", id_prog, 
   "REVISION_PROGRAMME.ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME", revisions.ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME, 
    "BARRAGE.Id", id_bar);



   //the main method



  public JsonResult getAllPara(int id_org, int id_bar, int id_prog, int id_rev)
    {
        List<string[]> listeval = new List<string[]>();
        string[,] matrixStr = new string[24, 1];
        string[,] matrix = new string[24, 14];
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = "";
            }
        }

        // revisions
        FNHSessionManager<REVISION_PROGRAMME> sessionManagerRev = new 
  FNHSessionManager<REVISION_PROGRAMME>
  (FNHSessionManager<REVISION_PROGRAMME>.DatabaseType.Oracle);
        FNHRepository<REVISION_PROGRAMME> repositoryRev = new 
  FNHRepository<REVISION_PROGRAMME>(sessionManagerRev);
        REVISION_PROGRAMME revisions = 
  repositoryRev.RetrieveByTreeColumn("PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL.ID_PROGRAMME", id_prog, 
  "ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME", (long)id_rev, "ORGANISATION.Id", id_org);

        // previsions
        FNHSessionManager<PREVISION> sessionManagerPrev = new 
   FNHSessionManager<PREVISION>(FNHSessionManager<PREVISION>.DatabaseType.Oracle);
        FNHRepository<PREVISION> repositoryPrev = new FNHRepository<PREVISION>
   (sessionManagerPrev);

        // retenue
        int id_retenue;
        FNHSessionManager<object> sessionManager1 = new FNHSessionManager<object>
 (FNHSessionManager<object>.DatabaseType.Oracle);
        NHibernate.ISession session = sessionManager1.Session;
        var sql = "select id_retenue from retenue where ID_BAR = " + id_bar + " and 
 ID_ORGANISATION = " + id_org;
        if (session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).UniqueResult() == null)
        { id_retenue = -1; }
        else
        { id_retenue = Convert.ToInt32(session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).UniqueResult()); }

        FNHSessionManager<RETENUE_AB> sessionManagerRet = new 
  FNHSessionManager<RETENUE_AB>(FNHSessionManager<RETENUE_AB>.DatabaseType.Oracle);
        FNHRepository<RETENUE_AB> repositoryRSet = new FNHRepository<RETENUE_AB>
  (sessionManagerRet);
        RETENUE_AB retenue = new RETENUE_AB();
        if (id_retenue != -1)
        {
            retenue = repositoryRSet.RetrieveListByTreeColumn("ORGANISATION.Id", id_org, 
  "BARRAGE.Id", id_bar, "Id", id_retenue).First();
        }
        else retenue = null;

        if (revisions != null)
        {

            IList<PREVISION> previsions = 
  repositoryPrev.RetrieveListByFourColumn("ORGANISATION.Id", id_org, 
  "PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL.ID_PROGRAMME", id_prog, 
  "REVISION_PROGRAMME.ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME", revisions.ID_REVISION_PROGRAMME, 
  "BARRAGE.Id", id_bar);

            DateTime date = revisions.DATE_REVISION;
            int mois_rev = date.Month;

            if (mois_rev > 9)
            {
                column = mois_rev - 9 + 1;
            }
            else if (mois_rev < 9)
            {
                column = mois_rev + 4;
            }
            else { column = 1; }


            if (retenue != null)
            {
                date_proche_bath = get_date_bath_proche(retenue.Id, id_org, date);

                foreach (var item in previsions)
                {
                    long mois = item.MOIS_PREVISION;
                    switch (mois)
                    {
                        case 01:
                            matrix = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.remplirCol(item, 5, 
    id_org, id_bar, date_proche_bath, mois);
                            break;
                        case 02:
                            matrix = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.remplirCol(item, 6, 
    id_org, id_bar, date_proche_bath, mois);
                            break;
                        case 03:
                            matrix = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.remplirCol(item, 7, 
   id_org, id_bar, date_proche_bath, mois);
                            break;
                        case 04:
                            matrix = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.remplirCol(item, 8, 
  id_org, id_bar, date_proche_bath, mois);
                            break;
                        case 05:
                            matrix = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.remplirCol(item, 9, 
  id_org, id_bar, date_proche_bath, mois);
                            break;
                        case 06:
                            matrix = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.remplirCol(item, 10, 
  id_org, id_bar, date_proche_bath, mois);
                            break;
                        case 07:
                            matrix = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.remplirCol(item, 11,    
  id_org, id_bar, date_proche_bath, mois);
                            break;
                        case 08:
                            matrix = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.remplirCol(item, 12, 
  id_org, id_bar, date_proche_bath, mois);
                            break;
                        case 09:
                            matrix = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.remplirCol(item, 1, 
  id_org, id_bar, date_proche_bath, mois);
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            matrix = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.remplirCol(item, 2, 
  id_org, id_bar, date_proche_bath, mois);
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            matrix = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.remplirCol(item, 3, 
   id_org, id_bar, date_proche_bath, mois);
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            matrix = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.remplirCol(item, 4, 
   id_org, id_bar, date_proche_bath, mois);
                            break;
                        default:
                            matrix = null;
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        // test
        FNHSessionManager<COURBE_ALERTE> sessionManager = new 
     FNHSessionManager<COURBE_ALERTE> 

     (FNHSessionManager<COURBE_ALERTE>.DatabaseType.Oracle);
        FNHRepository<COURBE_ALERTE> repository = new FNHRepository<COURBE_ALERTE>
     (sessionManager);
        IList<COURBE_ALERTE> courbeAlerte = 
     repository.RetrieveListByTwoColumn("ORGANISATION.Id", id_org, "BARRAGE.Id", 
     id_bar);
        if (courbeAlerte.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in courbeAlerte)
            {
                if (item.MOIS >= 9 && item.MOIS <= 12)
                {
                    matrix[22, item.MOIS - 9 + 1] = item.COURBE_SUP.ToString();
                    matrix[23, item.MOIS - 9 + 1] = item.COURBE_INF.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    matrix[22, item.MOIS + 3 + 1] = item.COURBE_SUP.ToString();
                    matrix[23, item.MOIS + 3 + 1] = item.COURBE_INF.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        // fin test

        matrix[0, 13] = matrix[0, column];
        matrix[1, 13] = matrix[1, column];
        matrix[2, 13] = matrix[2, column];
        matrix[3, 13] = matrix[3, column];
        matrix[4, 13] = matrix[4, column];

        matrix[5, 13] = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.Total_Ligne(5);
        matrix[10, 13] = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.Total_Ligne(10);
        matrix[11, 13] = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.Total_Ligne(11);
        matrix[12, 13] = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.Total_Ligne(12);
        matrix[13, 13] = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.Total_Ligne(13);
        matrix[14, 13] = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.Total_Ligne(14);
        matrix[15, 13] = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.Total_Ligne(15);
        matrix[16, 13] = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.Total_Ligne(16);
        matrix[17, 13] = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.Total_Ligne(17);
        matrix[18, 13] = MethodeStatistiqueCalcul.Total_Ligne(18);
        matrix[19, 13] = matrix[19, 12];
        matrix[20, 13] = matrix[20, 12];

        if (matrix[13, 13].ToString() != "" && matrix[18, 13].ToString() != "" && 
        matrix[18, 13].ToString() != "0")
        {
            matrix[21, 13] = Math.Round((Shared.convstr(matrix[13, 13]) / 
        Shared.convstr(matrix[18, 13])) * 100, 2).ToString();
        }
        // les noms 
        matrixStr[0, 0] = "Hauteur (m)";
        matrixStr[1, 0] = "Volume (Mm3)";
        matrixStr[2, 0] = "Cote contrainte (mNGM)";
        matrixStr[3, 0] = "Réserve utile (Mm3)";

        matrixStr[4, 0] = "Fréquence (Hrz)";
        matrixStr[5, 0] = "Apports freq";
        matrixStr[6, 0] = "Année type";
        matrixStr[7, 0] = "Apports type";
        matrixStr[8, 0] = "Année min";
        matrixStr[9, 0] = "Apports min";

        matrixStr[10, 0] = "Evaporation";
        matrixStr[11, 0] = "Fuites";

        matrixStr[12, 0] = "AEP";
        matrixStr[13, 0] = "Irrigation";
        matrixStr[14, 0] = "Turbinage Exclusif";
        matrixStr[15, 0] = "Déversé+Vidangé";
        matrixStr[16, 0] = "Autres Restit";

        matrixStr[17, 0] = "Dotation AEP";
        matrixStr[18, 0] = "Dotation Irrig";

        matrixStr[19, 0] = "V(m+1)";
        matrixStr[20, 0] = "Vu(m+1)";

        matrixStr[21, 0] = "Taux de satisfaction (%)";
        matrixStr[22, 0] = "Courbe d'alerte sup";
        matrixStr[23, 0] = "Courbe d'alerte inf";

        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            string[] temp = new string[14];
            for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    temp[0] = matrixStr[i, j];
                }
                else
                {
                    temp[j] = matrix[i, j];
                }
            }
            listeval.Add(temp);
        }

        var jsonData = new
        {
            rows =
            (from freq in listeval

             select new
            {
                cell = freq
            }).ToArray()
        };

        sessionManagerRev.Dispose();
        sessionManagerPrev.Dispose();
        sessionManager1.Dispose();
        sessionManagerRet.Dispose();
        sessionManager.Dispose();

        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

the problem arise only when table prevision is not empty, when it's empty no problem

Comment: Are you sure that `this.REVISION_PROGRAMME` is never `null`? You haven't build any checks if NOT.

Comment: Why do you specify the column names all the time? This is retrieved - via reflection - form the property name by Fluent NHibernate.

Comment: Wat is your Main method? We only see the mappings now. As @peer states, the mapping seems fine.

Comment: the problem only in the insruction of retrieving collection of previsions

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code, the .net runtime is just finishing some threads. They can be from the UI doing some multi threading. Nothing to worry about. There is more going on than only your code (async handling, memory management, etc), some stuff is just handled in the background. 'code 0' means that they where successfull.

Comment: but where's the problem exactly

Comment: You do not have a problem, exited with code 0 (0x0) means a thread has ended succesfully.

Comment: i want to say it does not return any result, and the method when were used stop in this point does not continue execution and my laptop warp up with a hign speed in fan.

Comment: Use a db monitory tool (sql profiler) to see what query runs/ and returns. The stopping threads have nothing to do with not seeing a result.

Comment: when i make the same query in toad return the result with no problem